# Joining arrays Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have two arrays:

```
Array1 = [
  [{
    index: '1',
    value: '100'
  }, {
    index: '2',
    value: '200'
  }],
  [{
    index: '1.1',
    value: '100'
  }, {
    index: '1.2',
    value: '200'
  }]
];

Array2 = [
  [{
    index: '10',
    value: '100'
  }, {
    index: '20',
    value: '200'
  }],
  [{
    index: '10.1',
    value: '100'
  }, {
    index: '10.2',
    value: '200'
  }]
]
```

How can I join the two arrays so that, the resulting array would be

```
ResultArray = [
  [{
    index: '1',
    value: '100'
  }, {
    index: '2',
    value: '200'
  }, {
    index: '10',
    value: '100'
  }, {
    index: '20',
    value: '200'
  }],
  [
    [{
      index: '1.1',
      value: '100'
    }, {
      index: '1.2',
      value: '200'
    }], {
      index: '10.1',
      value: '100'
    }, {
      index: '10.2',
      value: '200'
    }
  ]
]
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Show what you have attempted so far.

Comment: Hello, and welcome to StackOverflow! Please review the [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) guide and edit your question appropriately. How do you start off with those two arrays? What mental process are you using to determine the final structure?

Comment: `ResultArray = [Array1, Array2]`?

Comment: it _looks_ like he wants any items with decimal values in the index in one array, and any other ones in the second sub-array

Comment: If you want `ResultArray = [Array1, Array2]`? Use `spread operator`. Solution is `ResultArray = [...Array1, ...Array2]`

Comment: @vol7ron it seems that the example not only do combination.

Comment: We shouldn't have to guess what you want. Your question **and attempt*i should tells us exactly what you want to achieve.

Comment: @vol7ron Yes you are correct. The expected result is weird. First merged the inner arrays of Array1 and then merged with Array2. What exact result you after @Ali???

Answer (score 0):

As comments said, you might need to separate them by whether index is integer string or float string.

Here's an example of how to do separation.

```js
Array1 = [
  [{
    index: '1',
    value: '100'
  }, {
    index: '2',
    value: '200'
  }],
  [{
    index: '1.1',
    value: '100'
  }, {
    index: '1.2',
    value: '200'
  }]
];

Array2 = [
  [{
    index: '10',
    value: '100'
  }, {
    index: '20',
    value: '200'
  }],
  [{
    index: '10.1',
    value: '100'
  }, {
    index: '10.2',
    value: '200'
  }]
]

ResultArray = [[],[]];

// first combine all of the elements.
var arr = [];
[...Array1, ...Array2].forEach(function(el){
  arr.push(...el);
})

// check all elements and set to result array
arr.forEach(function(el){
  // check whether it is integer or not to set to index 0 or 1
  // if Number(el.index) is integer, mod 1 will equal to 0, else it is float.
  var val = Number(el.index);
  if(val % 1 === 0)
    ResultArray[0].push(el);
  else
    ResultArray[1].push(el);
})

console.log(ResultArray);
```

Answer (score 0):

This could be made more efficient, but for simplicity it has been separated into two steps.  The first step is to flatten all the objects into one array.  The second is to bin their contents into an array based on their *index* value (integer vs float):

```js
let Array1 = [
  [{
    index: '1',
    value: '100'
  }, {
    index: '2',
    value: '200'
  }],
  [{
    index: '1.1',
    value: '100'
  }, {
    index: '1.2',
    value: '200'
  }]
];

let Array2 = [
  [{
    index: '10',
    value: '100'
  }, {
    index: '20',
    value: '200'
  }],
  [{
    index: '10.1',
    value: '100'
  }, {
    index: '10.2',
    value: '200'
  }]
]


let ResultArray = [...flatten(Array1), ...flatten(Array2)]
console.log('Step 1: Flatten\n', ResultArray)

ResultArray = ResultArray.reduce((acc, o) => {
  let val = +o['index'];
  (val % 1 === 0) ? acc[0].push(o): acc[1].push(o)
  return acc;
}, [[],[]]);
console.log('Step 2: Bin\n', ResultArray)

function flatten(arr) {
  return arr.reduce((acc, val) => Array.isArray(val) ? acc.concat(flatten(val)) : acc.concat(val), []);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply concat the source arrays, and loop over them. In each iteration, check if the `index` is a float or integer, and based on the decision, push the results to separate arrays.

```js
var arr1= [[{index:'1',value:'100'},{index:'2',value:'200'}],[{index:'1.1',value:'100'},{index:'1.2',value:'200'}]];
var arr2 = [[{index:'10',value:'100'},{index:'20',value:'200'}],[{index:'10.1',value:'100'},{index:'10.2',value:'200'}]];

var ints = [],
  floats = [];

function classify(items) {
  items.forEach(item => (/^\d+$/.test(item.index) ? ints : floats).push(item));
}

arr1.concat(arr2).forEach(classify);
console.log([ints, floats]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps! I executed this on atom as a javascript printing the list in the console log.

```js
var Array1 = [
  [{
    index:'1',
    value:'100'
  }, {
    index:'2',
    value:'200'
  }],
  [{
    index:'1.1',
    value:'100'
  }, {
    index:'1.2',
    value:'200'
  }]
];

var Array2 = [
  [{
    index:'10',
    value:'100'
  }, {
    index:'20',
    value:'200'
  }],
  [{
    index:'10.1',
    value:'100'
  }, {
    index:'10.2',
    value:'200'
  }]
];

Array1.push(Array2)

console.log(Array1)
```

Answer (score -1):

This code only works if Array1 and Array2 have the same size. This code combines the objects in Array1 and Array2 according to the respective keys.

```
var arr = [];
for (var i = 0; i < Array1.length; i++){
    arr.push(Array1[i].concat(Array2[i]));
}
console.log(arr);
```